# get value of cloned select

Tags: jquery, select, clone, onchange

I would like to get the class and value of the select on change after I clone and do onchange but It's only returning value for the original select. Pleae find my code below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Clone</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="input1" class="clonedInput">
    <select id="fields" class="select">
        <option>Test One</option>
        <option>Test Two</option>
        <option>Test Three</option>
        <option>Test Four</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button>Clone</button>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length, // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
            newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum).fadeIn('slow');
            newElem.find('select#fields').attr('class','select' + newNum).val('');
            $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
        })
    $('select').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val(),
        classx = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log(value + ' | ' + classx);
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: The val function will return nothing if you don't have value attribute in option tag.

Answer (score 0):

`$-operator` takes first occurrence in DOM, and it happens to be an original.

The simplest solution would be to position a clone element BEFORE an original in DOM structure.

You can do it by using [.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Another solution would be to change cloned element id/name and get value by id/name:

```
("#clonedElement").attr("id","myID");
```

Comment: The answer is real simple, the just add true inside the clone function

Comment: If you've found an answer then please either answer your own question and check it as accepted answer in order to question to be closed or accept an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix it is to give to jQuery's [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method the `true` parameter, to clone also event's handlers. Another way is to give some name to your event handler and attach it manually to your cloned node, or the third way is [to delegate events](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to your select tags with jQuery's [on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)):

```js
newElem = $('#input' + num).clone(true);
```

[example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/f4xk9/2/)

... or ....

```js
newElem.change(select_change_handler);
$('select').change(select_change_handler);
```

[example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/f4xk9/1/)

... or ...

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {
```

[example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/f4xk9/)